# Define method that could be accessed only from descendants within the same package

Tags: scala, access-modifiers

I'd like to specify somehow that a method could be accessed only from descendants that are defined in the same package. That is like *protected* but more restricted.

```
object Some {
  class Base {
    modifier[magic] def test() {
      println("ok")
    }
  }

  class Ok extends Base {
    test()
  }

  class ShouldFail {
    def fail(b : Base) {
      b.test()
    }
  }
}

object Another {
  class ShouldFail extends Some.Base {
    test()
  }
}
```

That is what I'd like to get

Comment: Where are the packages in your example? If I interpret what you mean correctly, `Some` is in some package `a` and `Another` is in a package `b`. Then, you have not the flexibility you desire: you can either use `private[a]`, but then `Some.ShouldFail` will pass. Or you can use `protected`, but then `Another.ShouldFail` will pass.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a solution, too verbose and with some overhead for accessing protected methods.

```
object Some {
  private[Some] class Access[T] private[Some] (aFun : () => T) {
    private[Some] def apply() : T = aFun()
  }
  private[Some] object Access {
    private[Some] def apply[T](aFun : () => T) : Access[T] = new Access(aFun)
  }

  class Base {
    private[this] def test() {
      println("ok")
    }
    protected val accessTest = Access( () => test() )
  }

  class Ok extends Base {
    accessTest()
  }

  class ShouldFail {
    def fail(b : Base) {
      b.accessTest()
    }
  }
}

object Another {
  class ShouldFail extends Some.Base {
    accessTest()
  }
}
```

The idea is to wrap method inside an object and chain permission restrictions between access modifiers for accessing object and accessing value inside object. That introduces overhead, though.